# How to use same variable name to instantiate the object of different classes

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a reference variable with same name and assign class objects to the same depending on the environment. Please check the sample code below.

```
class EnvA{

public void create(){
.....
   }
}
class EnvB{

public void create(){
.....
  }
}

class main{
EnvA obj = null;
EnvB obj= null;
public static void main(string[] args)
    if(itisEnvB)
        obj  = new EnvA();
     else
         obj  = new EnvB();
    //create method should be called depending on which environment is set
    obj.create();
}
```

In the above code I need `obj` to get assigned to object refernce of either `EnvA` or `EnvB`. Because i will use only `obj` in my entire "class main".

Comment: You could use an interface to "expose" create. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: But in the main i can't use the same name for object creation. it's throwing duplicate variable name error

Comment: see Eran's answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I made the interface and implemented to all my class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should define an interface having the `create()` method, and both `EnvA` and `EnvB` should implement it.

Then the type of `obj` would by the type of that interface.

```
public interface Createable
{
    public void create();
}

class EnvA implements Createable {...}

class EnvB implements Createable {...}

...

Createable obj = null;
if(itisEnvB) {
    obj = new EnvA ();
} else {
    obj = new EnvB ();
}
obj.create();
```

Note that in order to refer to `obj` in your `main` method, it should either be a static member of your class or a local variable of the `main` method.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply. My code is working now.